# Redistribuir resultados de uma query em um array de duas dimensões

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte consulta no BD, que me retorna três informações: **nome, local, total**

```
list ($usuarios,$linha,$total) = buscarTopController(); 
do{ 
   echo $linha['nome'];
   echo $linha['local'];
   echo $linha['total'];
}while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($usuarios));
```

Queria que cada um desses valores fosse armazenado em uma posição de um mesmo array.

Exemplo:

Na posição : `$array[0][0]` fosse armazenado o valor de `$linha['nome'];`, na posição `$array[0][1]`  o valor de **local** e em `$array[0][2]` o valor de **total**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda

```
list ($usuarios,$linha,$total) = buscarTopController(); 
do{ 
    $array[] = array($linha['nome'],$linha['local'], $linha['total']);
}while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($usuarios));
```